# htmlspecialchars and ampersand in forms?

Tags: php, forms, url, html-entities

I have a little static function so that I can easily build html valid urls on my local website, it is below;

```
public static function url($path = false) {

    // Build return url with special html characters escaped
    return 'http://127.0.0.1/' . htmlspecialchars($path);
}
```

I have two urls one inside an anchor and another is inside a form action, they are below;

```
Root::url('test?category=' . $category . '&index=' . $index) // Href

Root::url('test?category=' . $_GET['category'] . '&index=' . $_GET['index']) // Form
```

`GET === $`, you can see inside my static function that I use `htmlspecialchars` to escape special html characters from my url.

The anchor one returns a valid link and works as expected. The form one however returns the following, as in when I click on the form submit, my url in my browser is as follows.

```
http://127.0.0.1/test?category=innate&amp;index=0
```

Why is this? My website breaks because it is dependant on the `GET` parameters being valid.

Thanks for your time, hope this made sense.

**EDIT**

I insert the return value of the function call straight into my form action,

```
<form 
action="<?= Root::url('test?category=' . $_GET['category'] . '&index=' . $_GET['index']); ?>" 
method="post">
```

**EDIT**

The form html is as follows;

```
<form action="http://example.com/test?category=innate&amp;index=0" method="post">
```

The anchor html is as follows

```
<a href="http://example.com/test?category=innate&amp;index=0">
```

Could it be something to do with the server sending a POST request even though I have GET parameters?

**EDIT #3**

Ok so it has something to do with my function or what I am passing in, I hard typed in the url in the form submit and it worked, no problems, which means it can only be what my function is returning.

I myself cannot see what I may be!

**ANSWER**

After the form was being submitted, I was redirecting to the same page using `header` to counter form resubmission. The string for the header was being generated by `Root::url()`.

Two hours this took me to figure out, but boy does it feel good!

Comment: It looks like the output of `Root::url` is being escaped again between the point where you call the function and the point where you insert the result into the HTML.

Comment: I insert it straight into the html, i'll edit my question to show you,

Comment: how about a you transfer it with `urlencode` and decode it with `htmlspecialchars(urldecode($whatever))` in your output?

Comment: I'll try that now thanks, why would this matter though, in my source it shows the same as the anchor, ie, just one `&amp;`, but the browser doesn't change it when the submit is clicked, it is wierd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you wouldn't add a query string to a POST URL. It's not forbidden, though, it may only be somewhat confusing, especially if you use `$_REQUEST` (which you don't, it seems).

I don't know why your browser shows an uninterpreted `&amp;`, it should interpret it.

Your problems are likely due to one of these:

1. a bad browser - try another one
2. bad content of the form input fields
3. other

Comment: Tried in chrome, mozilla, safari and ie, still the same. Am trying to figure it out by testing, will let you know. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @ProfessorIQ, do you by chance have some javascript that intercepts the submit?

Comment: No javascript but I have fine tuned the problem to something specific, please check my edit :) Thanks

Comment: As I wrote, having a query string in a POST request is not a problem. If your HTML is like that, and you see the POST URL with the uninterpreted `&amp;`, my guess is that there is something in between that does an extra `htmlspecialchars` equivalent

Comment: I found out what it was!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite logic.

I assume your `url()` method looks like this:

```
url($string){
  echo htmlspecialchars($string);
}
```

Let's have a look at the `$string` you are passing:

```
'test?category=' . $_GET['category'] . '&index=' . $_GET['index'];
```

As I see in your output, replacing the values, the final string before `htmlspecialchars()` occur would be:

`'test?category=innate&index=0'` and after it: `test?category=innate&amp;index=0`

---

What happened here? you first concatenated the string, and then `htmlspecialchars()`'ed the & used to separate the parameters. And to not break the url, you don't want to convert **THAT** '&'.

Also to sanitize the url you shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars()` because most html entities would convert to somthing like **&** + somename + **;** for example the Euro symbol would convert to `&euro;` and you don't want the actual & symbol in your url, the browsers will interpret it as you have another new parameter awaiting.

You should use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), which will convert your & into: %26 , also, the function's name is self-explanatory, it's encoding a string to use on a URL.

---

Still, you want the & to separate the parameters, but not in the `$GET` values. What should we do? to `urlencode` the values before concatenating the string. I would suggest a method like this one:

```
function url($page, $get){
    $parameters = array();
    foreach($get as $k => $v) $parameters[] = urlencode($k)."=".urlencode($v);
    //We are concatenating with ? and & the urlencoded() values in the next line:
    echo urlencode($page).'?'.implode('&', $parameters);
}

url('test', $_GET); // outputs: test?category=innate&index=0
```

This would get rid of the special chars from a form's field names and values.

I noticed you will use 2 fixed parameters, category and index, so the method could be like this:

```
function url($page, $get){
    $page = urlencode($page);
    $category = urlencode($get['category']);
    $index = urlencode($get['index']);
    echo "$page?category=$category&index=$index";
}
```

Hope this is what you needed

Comment: This is very good and informative but not what it was, thanks for your time.